# What if an attacker knows 1 bit of a OTP ciphertext

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

I want to know the  answer for the question above, given that we encrypt a message that ends with a "0" and the encryption key is concatenated with a "0" to, in that case that case the cyphertext would also end with a zero, knowing that the attacker would know that the last bit of the key and the message is the same, would that cause a problem in case we're using a OTP to encrypt our messages?

Comment: What is "a OPT ciphertext"? ​ ​

Comment: I'm sorry I meant OTP for one time pad i just corrected it !

Comment: Didn't we just have another question about this same exercise?

Comment: I don't think so sorry

Comment: Ah, [here it is.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40145/proving-perfect-secrecy-for) IMO, that question was kind of poorly asked, though, so I'm *not* voting to close yours as a duplicate of it.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what I wanted to know though is that, if an attacker knows 1 bit from the encrypted text, could that reveal any information about the original message ?

Comment: TL;DR: No, because the attacker learns nothing new about the message from having the cipher text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this wouldn't cause problems.
The reason for this is the way how perfect secrecy is defined.
The definition says that a scheme is perfectly secret if an attacker doesn't learn anything new about the message when giving a cipher text, [also see my other answer for a more "mathy" formulation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31086/23623).

So an attacker knows a certain bit is fixed, thus he can't *ever* learn anything new about it from the cipher text. And he also can't learn anything new about the rest of the message because only the corresponding key bit is fixed and the rest of the key stream is still uniformly and independently random and is thus still an OTP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you made things very clear for me thanks again!